# SQL: Optimize nested query with redundant union code?

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery, query-optimization, union

Although the below query works perfectly fine for my uses, I am trying to understand if there is a way to optimize, since it uses the same nested subquery in both statements of the UNION. My instincts say there should be a way to look up the subquery once and use that result for both parts of the UNION, but I am running into syntactic issues when trying to use join across the UNIONs.

```
SELECT ClientLocalName, ClientLocalID, ClientMasterID, 1 HierarchyType
    FROM dbo.ClientLocal
    WHERE clientLocalID = 
        ANY (SELECT HierarchyItem FROM dbo.ClientPhone WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '%0123456789')
UNION
SELECT ClientMasterName, '0', clientMasterID, 2
    FROM dbo.ClientMaster
    WHERE clientMasterID = 
        ANY (SELECT HierarchyItem FROM dbo.ClientPhone WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '%0123456789')
ORDER BY HierarchyType ASC;
```

To help explain why the original query is necessary, imagine a concept of a "local" client and a "master" client -- the local client is tied to a master client, but the master client may or may not have any local clients. Likewise, the phone number associated with each should only be tied to either the local client or the master client (hence why in the second statement, a '0' is hardcoded for the local client ID -- because there is no association).

This would be running against Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 by the way.

Comment: Just because you repeat the code, doesn't necessarily mean, that it is evaluated repeatedly. Chances are, the optimizer catches that this is repeated and reuses the result of the first evaluation. Unless, a reevaluation seems more opportune of course. If it's just about repeating the code, go with the CTE solutions provided.

Comment: There could be quite a bit in this query to be optimized. First, I don't see how this query could run, since you can't `UNION` `ClientLocalName` and `ClientMasterName` unless those columns have the same name. Can you provide a small bit of sample data and your expected results? A CTE for the `ClientPhone` will work, but is that actually the data you're looking to get?

Comment: @Shawn the name of the columns doesn't matter as long as the data type is the same across Unions. The query does work just fine. Anyway Lukasz' answer provides what I'm looking for.

Comment: @stickybit correct but the real code will have more conditions in the repeated code and so there is a good incentive here to not duplicate.

Comment: @stickybit: In fact, the repeated code is bound to be evaluated multiple times. Sure, the base data will only need to be loaded into the cache once, but the actual execution is done as often as asked for. See my example below.

Comment: @deroby: The problem is, in a declarative language like SQL you don't ask for execution, you describe a result. In general, leaving the possibility to give hints in certain SQL dialects out of the picture, it's the sole decision of the optimizer and query planner what actually is executed and what not and how many times etc.. I intentionally wrote "Chances are", as I cannot say for sure what decision they will actually make here. And I mentioned, that, if they think it's opportune they will reevaluate as often as they think it's good.

Comment: @Jon You know, in all my SQL years I've never really thought about that. The only requirement is that the number of columns and their order must be the same and and datatype be convertible. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4a2dd/1)  Name doesn't matter. I always tried to make sure they had the same name (or a common alias) because it makes it clear what the column is. Apparently you can use a `varchar(10)` `UNION`ed to a `char(5)`, and the column will be named the first `SELECT` with the largest datatype of the `UNION`ed columns. Add that to the things I never knew I didn't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't like repeating code you could use common table expression:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT HierarchyItem FROM dbo.ClientPhone WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '%0123456789'
)
SELECT ClientLocalName, ClientLocalID, ClientMasterID, 1 HierarchyType
FROM dbo.ClientLocal
WHERE clientLocalID IN (SELECT HierarchyItem FROM cte)
UNION
SELECT ClientMasterName, '0', clientMasterID, 2
FROM dbo.ClientMaster
WHERE clientMasterID IN (SELECT HierarchyItem FROM cte)
ORDER BY HierarchyType ASC;
```

Comment: Worth to mention, that changing `UNION` to `UNION ALL` can change the overall result, if there are duplicates in the subresults (the `SELECT`s acting as operands to the `UNION` or `UNION ALL`). The naming of the columns (`ClientLocalID` and `ClientMasterID`) suggests, that there are PKs in the subresults, hence duplicates cannot occur. But if this is a false impression the subresults need to be made duplicate free on their own by using a `SELECT DISTINCT` when using `UNION ALL` (which might still be faster as the sets to deduplicate are smaller).

Comment: @stickybit Good catch.

Comment: This provides the same results (for this query) and provides all of the best possible "optimizations" that I can see. The repeating code is going to be more important because the CTE is going to have more conditions, clauses (and thus more arguments in JDBC), so this is going to save some code in quite a few places. From an execution time standpoint looks to be just as efficient or better.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody seems to mention it: having less code does not necessarily mean that it will be faster in execution too. Too often people seem to think that CTE's are executed first (or "in order" in case there are multiple of them) and then the final query is applied; they are NOT. In fact, the server will pretty much handle the cte as if it was a derived table somewhere in the FROM or JOIN clause and as such pick exactly the same query plan to execute them. In order avoid the system to have to scan the `ClientPhone` table twice (`LIKE '%0123...'` is a very 'annoying' operation) you'd have to do it once upfront, store the result in a temp-table and then use said temp-table in your actual query.

To give some context to this, I took the liberty to create some sample-data (see code below). The results of my test were:

- The original query takes 71ms
- The CTE version takes 71ms and uses the EXACT same query plan
- The creation of the temp-table takes 26ms, the query using it 23ms

So even though the server needs to create the temp-table and fill it, combined the latter still only takes 49ms instead of the original 71ms!

Off course your mileage may vary depending on the number of records involved and the complexity of the repeated query, like I said, `LIKE '%blah'` is an annoying thing to do because it requires a full scan of the table (or with a bit of luck of a (covering) index). If it had been `WHERE pk_field = @value` the effect might have been very different)

Happy querying...

```
IF DB_ID('test') IS NULL CREATE DATABASE test
GO
USE test
GO

-- setup
IF OBJECT_ID('ClientPhone') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ClientPhone 
IF OBJECT_ID('ClientLocal') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ClientLocal
IF OBJECT_ID('ClientMaster') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ClientMaster
GO
SELECT TOP 50000 
       HierarchyItem = IDENTITY(int, 1, 1),
       PhoneNumber   = Convert(varchar(100), NewID())
  INTO dbo.ClientPhone 
  FROM sys.objects x1, sys.columns x2, sys.objects x3, sys.columns x4

SELECT ClientLocalName = 'client dummy', 
       ClientLocalID   = Convert(int, Rand(HierarchyItem * 37) * 50000), 
       ClientMasterID   = Convert(int, Rand(HierarchyItem * 47) * 50000), 
       HierarchyType   = 1
  INTO dbo.ClientLocal
  FROM dbo.ClientPhone 

SELECT ClientMasterName = 'master dummy', 
       ClientLocalID    = Convert(int, Rand(HierarchyItem * 51) * 50000), 
       ClientMasterID   = Convert(int, Rand(HierarchyItem * 53) * 50000), 
       HierarchyType    = 2
  INTO dbo.ClientMaster
  FROM dbo.ClientPhone 

GO
-- original 
SELECT ClientLocalName, ClientLocalID, ClientMasterID, 1 HierarchyType
  FROM dbo.ClientLocal
 WHERE ClientLocalID = ANY (SELECT HierarchyItem FROM dbo.ClientPhone WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '%01')
UNION
SELECT ClientMasterName, '0', ClientMasterID, 2
  FROM dbo.ClientMaster
 WHERE ClientMasterID = ANY (SELECT HierarchyItem FROM dbo.ClientPhone WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '%01')
ORDER BY HierarchyType ASC;

-- CTE
;WITH cte
   AS (SELECT HierarchyItem FROM dbo.ClientPhone WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '%01')

SELECT ClientLocalName, ClientLocalID, ClientMasterID, 1 HierarchyType
  FROM dbo.ClientLocal
 WHERE ClientLocalID = ANY (SELECT HierarchyItem FROM cte)
UNION
SELECT ClientMasterName, '0', ClientMasterID, 2
  FROM dbo.ClientMaster
 WHERE ClientMasterID = ANY (SELECT HierarchyItem FROM cte)
ORDER BY HierarchyType ASC;

-- temp table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ClientPhone') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ClientPhone

SELECT HierarchyItem INTO #ClientPhone FROM dbo.ClientPhone WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '%01'

SELECT ClientLocalName, ClientLocalID, ClientMasterID, 1 HierarchyType
  FROM dbo.ClientLocal
 WHERE ClientLocalID = ANY (SELECT HierarchyItem FROM #ClientPhone)
UNION
SELECT ClientMasterName, '0', ClientMasterID, 2
  FROM dbo.ClientMaster
 WHERE ClientMasterID = ANY (SELECT HierarchyItem FROM #ClientPhone)
ORDER BY HierarchyType ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with subQry as (
    SELECT ClientLocalName, ClientLocalID, ClientMasterID
        FROM dbo.ClientLocal
        WHERE clientLocalID = 
            ANY (SELECT HierarchyItem FROM dbo.ClientPhone WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '%0123456789')
)
SELECT ClientLocalName, ClientLocalID, ClientMasterID, 1 HierarchyType
    FROM subQry
UNION
SELECT ClientMasterName, '0', clientMasterID, 2
    FROM subQry
ORDER BY HierarchyType ASC;
```

Comment: Because the subQry uses dbo.ClientLocal, the overall query finds the local IDs twice and doesn't find any of the MasterIDs

Comment: You're right.  I didn't realize you are querying 2 differents tables.  So, I think the best way is Lukasz Szozda answer.

Comment: You can try this.  Not sure if this help for performance.  I think this will be the same.

    WITH cte AS (
      SELECT distinct HierarchyItem FROM dbo.ClientPhone WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '%0123456789'
    )
    SELECT ClientLocalName, ClientLocalID, ClientMasterID, 1 HierarchyType
    FROM dbo.ClientLocal inner join CTE on ClientLocal.clientLocalID = cte.HierarchyItem
    UNION
    SELECT ClientMasterName, '0', clientMasterID, 2
    FROM dbo.ClientMaster inner join cte on ClientMaster.clientMasterID = cte.HierarchyItem
    ORDER BY HierarchyType ASC;

Answer (score 0):

The only obvious optimization I can see is to use `union all` instead of `union`:

```
SELECT ClientLocalName, ClientLocalID, ClientMasterID, 1 HierarchyType
FROM dbo.ClientLocal
WHERE clientLocalID = ANY (SELECT HierarchyItem FROM dbo.ClientPhone WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '%0123456789')
UNION ALL
SELECT ClientMasterName, '0', clientMasterID, 2
FROM dbo.ClientMaster
WHERE clientMasterID = ANY (SELECT HierarchyItem FROM dbo.ClientPhone WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '%0123456789')
ORDER BY HierarchyType ASC;
```

You clearly have no duplicates between the sub-selects (because of the last column).  This assumes you have no duplicates within each sub-select either.

I don't know about SQL Server's treatment of `= ANY`, but I assume it is basically the same as `IN`.  The `= ANY` subquery would be run once (for each subquery), but the second time the results would be cached.  You could simplify this to:

```
SELECT ClientLocalName, ClientLocalID, ClientMasterID, 1 HierarchyType
FROM ((SELECT ClientLocalName, ClientLocalID, ClientMasterID
       FROM dbo.ClientLocal
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT ClientLocalName, '0', ClientMasterID
       FROM dbo.ClientMasterName
      ) 
     ) c        
WHERE c.clientLocalID = ANY (SELECT HierarchyItem FROM dbo.ClientPhone WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '%0123456789')
ORDER BY HierarchyType ASC;
```

I don't know if this would be much of an improvement.

The `LIKE` pattern has a wildcard at the beginning of the number, making that hard to optimize.

Comment: Worth to mention, that changing `UNION` to `UNION ALL` can change the overall result, if there are duplicates in the subresults (the `SELECT`s acting as operands to the `UNION` or `UNION ALL`). The naming of the columns (`ClientLocalID` and `ClientMasterID`) suggests, that there are PKs in the subresults, hence duplicates cannot occur. But if this is a false impression the subresults need to be made duplicate free on their own by using a `SELECT DISTINCT` when using `UNION ALL` (which might still be faster as the sets to deduplicate are smaller).

Comment: Unfortunately the fundamental problem here is the WHERE uses a different column in the predicate -- in the first it is clientLocalID and in the second it is clientMasterID -- even though both are the same type and formatted the same, because the column names are different this will exclude the clientMasterIDs from the results.